# How do I get the Android 4 web browser to read arbitrary web pages out loud?

Tags: text-to-speech

Can the Android browser in ICS read any web page out loud with TalkBack? How? It reads user interface elements, and some parts of specially scripted web pages (google.com) but I don't see how to make it read ordinary web pages.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how to achieve this natively -- but you could try [Talking Clipboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.talkingclipboard.android), which can not only read everything you copy to the clipboard -- but also handle web pages directly. It even supports picking the web page's address from Pocket / Read-it-Later, can read from arbitrary text/html files stored locally, and also ePub books.